# Compute volume between plane and cylinder with triple integrals in spherical coordinates

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, volume

I need to compute the following volume in spherical coordinates:[image]

where the angle between the base of the cylinder of radius $R$ and the plane is $30º$.

I already computed the equation of the plane with 3 points: $x+ \sqrt3 z =0$. After that, I decided to use cylindrical coordinates and it was pretty straightfoward:

$$V= \int_{\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{3\pi}{2}} \int_{0}^{R} \int_{0}^{\frac{-r \cos(\theta)}{\sqrt3}} r \mathrm{dz}\mathrm{dr}\mathrm{d \theta} = \frac{2R^3}{3 \sqrt3}.$$

However, I need to get the result using spherical coordinates. When I tried to get the volume in spherical coordinates I got the following:

$$V =\int_{\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{3\pi}{2}} \int_{\frac{\pi}{3}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \int_{0}^{R\csc(\phi)} r^2 \sin(\phi) \mathrm{dr}\mathrm{d \phi}\mathrm{d \theta} = \frac{\pi R^3}{3 \sqrt3}.$$

I am pretty sure that the result in the cylindrical coordinates is correct, but I don't know why my result in spherical coordinates is wrong. Any hints about the integration limits are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note that $\phi$ and $\theta$ are not independent of each other.

$x = \rho \cos\theta \sin \phi, y = \rho \sin \theta \sin \phi, z = \rho \cos\phi$

$\phi$ and $\theta$ are bound by the plane $x + \sqrt3 z = 0 \implies \rho (\cos\theta \sin\phi + \sqrt3 \cos\phi) = 0$

$tan \phi =  - \sqrt3 \sec \theta$

So the volume integral should be,

$V = \displaystyle \int_{\pi/2}^{3\pi/2} \int_{\arctan(- \sqrt3 \sec \theta)}^{\pi/2} \int_0^{R \csc \phi} \rho^2 \sin \phi \ d\rho \ d\phi \ d\theta$